# BY-if then do-if first then delete: how to write this in HIVE?

Tags: hive, sas, hql

How do I write this in HIVE?
This table has duplicates and based on the first unique column I want to exclude the duplicate records from the new table.

[image: Sample tables]

```
 data new;
    set old;
    by Col_1  Col_2date  Col_3date;

    if Col_2date ^=  Col_3date then do;
        if first.Col_3Date ^= 1 then delete;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: So you just want to select the first observation when sorted by those three columns?  What does it mean when COL_2DATE is equal to COL_3DATE?

Comment: Thanks Tom, I added sample table and some explanation. I hope it helps, I am new to this so any tips would be great!

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
select min(Obs)  as Obs, Col_11, Col_2date, Col_3date
  from your_table
 group by Col_11, Col_2date, Col_3date
```